# UITableView textlabel frame not showing proper

Tags: ios, uitableview

I developed iPhone app in which i have UITableView.

UITableViewCell `textlabel` frame is not proper according to text,

when i write this code, `UITableView` textlabel is not proper.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        
         static NSString *CategCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
                    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CategCellIdentifier];
                    if (cell == nil) {
                        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CategCellIdentifier];
                    }
                 
               cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
               cell.textLabel.font=  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
               cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
               cell.textLabel.text = [tempArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                      
                return cell;
        }
```

when i pass my array to UITableView it shows like this:

**Whats the problem ? where i am doing mistake, please help**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what text your array contains. But, I have created an example of my own. Here is the code :

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CategCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CategCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CategCellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.font=  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Brand";

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

**Here is the output :**

[image]

I have used your code. Only difference I made is, I am applying red colour to text label in willDisplayCell: method of UITableViewDelegate.

Coming to the margins that appears on both sides of the tableview are as per Apple's UI guidelines.

Let me know if you need my code.

Comment: My problem is not the `cell.backgroundColor` problem is why the text label gets the improper height,  `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];` is only shown for understanding.

Comment: see your image you also facing the same problem as mine, see extreme left and extreme right in your image white space is occurring...

Comment: @Krunal, I have already mentioned in my post that "Coming to the margins that appears on both sides of the tableview are as per Apple's UI guidelines.". Its default behaviour of the UITableView. If you don't want margins, you need to use a custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: I have up voted your answer also accepted plz up vote my question

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Size to fit with content After setting Text.

```
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dude Still same problem exists

Comment: I am facing the problem in width of textlabel check here, http://i.imgur.com/GvflcZX.png

Answer (score 0):

Check table row height property in size inspector, may be some thing wrong with it

[tableView setRowHeight: 100.00];

or you can use delegate to set row height

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I am facing the problem in width of textlabel check here, http://i.imgur.com/GvflcZX.png